# MySQLDB Python performance

Tags: python, mysql, performance, cursor

when I write a lot of data into a DB, when is it necessary to get the cursor first. Is it a performance issue if I always want to a have a new cursor?

Cheers,
peeder

Comment: Why would you want a new cursor each time?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know, when I need a new cursor. Do I need a new cursor between an INSERT and a SELECT. Don't fully understand the cursor concept.

Comment: you don't, just reuse the same...

Comment: Since Python abuses the term "cursor", I am too confused to help you.